# Notepad++ how to automatically highlight .log files like in IDEs?

Tags: logging, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

How can I create a user defined language (UDL) in Notepad++ to highlight my logs like in other IDEs? So for example that INFO logs are green, DEBUG logs blue, ERROR logs red and so on?

[my wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQtaT.png)

Comment: This is not the way posting here on StackOverflow. Split your question into question and answer. You may accept your own answer two days later having 15 reputation points.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a new file `logSytanx.xml` with the following content. This script searches for the following keywords and colors the entire line after them: `TRACE` (purple), `DEBUG` (blue), `INFO` (green), `WARN` (yellow), `ERROR` (red).

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <UserLang name=".log" ext="log" udlVersion="2.1">
        <Settings>
            <Global caseIgnored="yes" allowFoldOfComments="no" foldCompact="no" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
            <Prefix Keywords1="yes" Keywords2="no" Keywords3="yes" Keywords4="yes" Keywords5="yes" Keywords6="no" Keywords7="no" Keywords8="no" />
        </Settings>
        <KeywordLists>
            <Keywords name="Comments">00WARN 01 02 03 04</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, extras1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, extras2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, range"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords3"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords4"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords5"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords6"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords7"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords8"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Delimiters">00 01 02 03INFO 04 05202 06DEBUG 07 08202 09ERROR 10 11202 12TRACE 13 14202 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</Keywords>
        </KeywordLists>
        <Styles>
            <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fgColor="FFFFFF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENTS" fgColor="0080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="7" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="LINE COMMENTS" fgColor="FFFF00" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="NUMBERS" fgColor="B2C57F" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS1" fgColor="00CA28" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS2" fgColor="0080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS3" fgColor="8000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS4" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS5" fgColor="FF0080" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS7" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="OPERATORS" fgColor="FF0080" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE1" fgColor="00FF80" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="7" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE2" fgColor="0080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="7" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN COMMENT" fgColor="0080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="7" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS1" fgColor="FF8040" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="3" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS2" fgColor="61D502" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS3" fgColor="4FA7FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS4" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS5" fgColor="8080FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS7" fgColor="C0C0C0" bgColor="FFFFFF" colorStyle="1" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        </Styles>
    </UserLang>
</NotepadPlus>
```

2. open Notepad++ → *Language* → *User defined language* → *Define your language...* → click button "*Import...*"
3. select `logSytanx.xml` for importing
4. that's it. Now files with *.log* extension will be automatically highlighted.